# React.js Dispatcher and setState() issue while dispatching an action

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am very new to react.js and flux architecture . I just created a very small example to understand the flow of flux architecture. But I am facing some issue after adding action and store. Here is my code:

Name.jsx ( Component )

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var NameActions = require('../actions/NameActions');
var NameStore = require('../stores/NameStore');

var Name = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {fname: 'Arjita', lname: 'Mitra'};
    },
    _changeIt: function() {

        var fName = this.state.fname;
        var lName = this.state.lname;

        var data = {fName: fName , lName: lName};

        NameActions.setName(data);
    },
    handleChange: function(field,e) {
        var nextState = {}
        nextState[field] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(nextState);
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className = "container">
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="idFname" value={this.state.fname}
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,'fname')}/>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="idLname" value={this.state.lname} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'lname')}/>
                    <button type="button" name="btnok" onClick={this._changeIt()}>Process</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Name;
```

NameActions.js

```
var ActionsHelper = require('./ActionsHelper');

var NameConstants = require('../constants/NameConstants');

var NameActions = {
    setName: function(value) {
        ActionsHelper.dispatch(NameConstants.SET_NAME, value);
    }
}

module.exports = NameActions;
```

NameConstants.js

```
var _BASE = "NAME_CONSTANTS";

function construct(value) {
    return _BASE + "_" + value;
}

module.exports = {
    SET_NAME : construct("SET_NAME")
};
```

NameStore.js

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var _ = require('underscore');

var NameConstants = require('../constants/NameConstants');

function setValue(value) {
    console.log(value);
}

var NameStore = _.extend({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    addChangeListener : function(callback) {
       this.on('change', callback);
   },
   emitChange : function() {
       this.emit('change');
   },
   removeChangeListener : function(callback) {
       this.removeListener('change', callback);
   }
});

AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
    var action = payload.action;
    var data = action.data;

    switch (action.actionType) {
        case NameConstants.SET_NAME :
            setValue(data.value);
            break;

        default :
            return true;
    }

    NameStore.emitChange();
    return true;
});

module.exports = NameStore;
```

Errors I am facing currently is as soon as I start typing in the name field its throwing warning -

Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
http://localhost:8080/js/bundle.js
Line 24836

Also another error is can't dispatch in the middle of dispatch.

I am stuck for a long time. Please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
<button type="button" name="btnok" onClick={this._changeIt()}>Process</button>
```

You are calling this._changeIt in your render when you mean to be passing a reference to it. You can fix this by changing it to the following:

```
<button type="button" name="btnok" onClick={this._changeIt.bind(this)}>Process</button>
```